# Hibernate - Select OneColumn and get result as list

Tags: java, hibernate

Lets say I have this table:

```
TableName: order;

Columns: id (numeric - primary key);

Data: 1, 2, 3, 5, 7;
```

I have a list of `id`s and I want to see which of them are in table `order`.

I execute this query direct in mysql:

```
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id IN (1, 3, 11, 17);
```

How I can execute this query with Hibernate and get as result `List<Integer>` which contain [1, 3](based on example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try storing the ids in a List then pass them to the query as a parameter, this is the way to execute your query though :

```
List<Long> ids = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 11, 17);
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id IN (?1)");
query.setParameterList(1, ids) ; 
List<Integer> id_result = query.getResultList();
```